# How do I get the URL parameters with AWS lambda functions?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-go

I am using Netlify functions for an API, most of which is working perfectly fine, apart from when I am needing to access URL parameters

Here is a snippet of what I have to get the parameter:

```golang
func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (Response, error) {

    id := request.PathParameters["id"]

    ...
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

I have other functions that are working correctly that do not require URL params but cannot figure out how to get these ones working, I have tried multiple different selections:

```
https://example.com/endpoint/1
https://example.com/endpoint/id=1
https://example.com/endpoint?id=1
```

None of the above return the id path parameter when hitting the endpoint

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events#APIGatewayProxyRequest

Comment: read the question again, already using APIGatewayProxyRequest

Comment: The thing you're already using as a field called `QueryStringParameters`. What exactly do you need clarification on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `request.QueryStringParameters["id"]` to get id from query param

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (Response, error) {

    id := request.QueryStringParameters["id"]

    ...
}
```

And call like `https://example.com/endpoint?id=1`